# Wget style dl manager - client side

Tags: javascript, download, wget, download-manager

Is it possible to write a barebones client side download manager - like wget - with javascript?

I found this anwer:
[Is there any javascript (and client-side) wget implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9149672/is-there-any-javascript-and-client-side-wget-implementation#)

That states it most likely is not possible. But most likely is not the same as no.

Then i found out this script:
https://gist.github.com/bitnetwork/b6f7ef23fac1044e5dfb1187fd1936af

But with no documentation on how it's used.

Comment: Do you intend it to be used in the browser, or in a console using node.js?

Comment: In the browser of the client. Thank you!